# touchSwipe pinch does not work

Tags: jquery, pinchzoom, swipe-gesture

I am using [touchSwipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin) library which works great if i only use either `swipe` or `pinch`. But if i use both of them, then `pinch` does not work. I have also seen their demo for [pinch+swipe](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Pinch_and_Swipe.html) and in that demo `pinch` also not working. Is there is anything which i am missing or this is some sort of bug?

**[FIDDLE FOR PINCH+SWIPE](http://jsfiddle.net/zajyjssa/11/)**

**[FIDDLE FOR PINCH ONLY](http://jsfiddle.net/zajyjssa/14/)**

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old (ish) question, but I recently had the same issue.

This issue was fixed on GitHub on 2nd Feb.
https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/commit/b70865e2d026e2506ec6e0d3d222f84308cdf483

Although the online pinch+swipe demo you referenced is still using an old version of the script and does not work.